# Export/Import Octet String via ldif

Tags: ldap, ldif, identity-management, edirectory

I need to transport Attributes from one LDAP Directory (Novell eDirectory) to another.
I use LDIF to do that.

But until now, i couldn´t find a way to import Octet Strings this way.
The export to ldif seems to work.

The Octet String Attributes i need to transport are:
sASLoginConfigurationKey
sASLoginConfiguration
sASLoginSecretKey
sASLoginSecret

Could anybody give me an hint to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work.
The attributes you are using have encrypted values that will only be able to be decoded from the Edirectory Tree you are exporting from. (ie the tree you are putting these in, must have the  SAME NICI key you took them from)

-jim

Comment: As Jim notes the data stored in these attributes are encrypted, and there is alas no way to get them out.  You might read Jim's answer as impling that it might be possible to reuse NICI keys, but I do not think that is really possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. But is there any other way to save the Attributes? Because we move out authentification to another eDir server and need to keep this attributes.

Comment: Although you maybe able to save the values, they will NOT work in when you move them to another eDir server if it is in another tree.

Comment: Ok...maybe i can transport the value via eDir2eDir Driver, instead of the export/import method?

Comment: No. They NICI Key is not transportable across different Edirectory Trees. Perhaps, you should explain your desired outcome and perhaps we could find a solution. (ie why do you want to export and import these values?)

Comment: Ok i try to explain...we have one authentification server (eDirectory) running IDM 2.x ... it is very old, so we have to stop this and move the authentification to an other server (this one is an already existing eDirectory with IDM 4.x). But if we can´t transport the Challenge&Response attributes to the new server we lose all this informations and all our users have to set new values. We want to avoid this.

Comment: I think you are stuck. You will loose the challenge-responses.